# Add a stream to an accumulator

Tags: python, pyspark, spark-streaming

In the sample code provided in the spark documentation, we have the following:

```
>>> from pyspark.accumulators import AccumulatorParam
>>> class VectorAccumulatorParam(AccumulatorParam):
...     def zero(self, value):
...         return [0.0] * len(value)
...     def addInPlace(self, val1, val2):
...         for i in xrange(len(val1)):
...              val1[i] += val2[i]
...         return val1
>>> va = sc.accumulator([1.0, 2.0, 3.0], VectorAccumulatorParam())
>>> va.value
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
>>> def g(x):
...     global va
...     va += [x] * 3
>>> rdd.foreach(g)
>>> va.value
[7.0, 8.0, 9.0]
```

However, if I was to create a stream and add the input from the stream to the accumulator, how would I go about doing that?

It seems like you can only add lists or no arrays to the accumulator but not dstreams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `va.add()` in `foreachRDD` or `transform` like :

```
sc = SparkContext()
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 3)


class VectorAccumulatorParam(AccumulatorParam):
    def zero(self, value):
        return [0] * len(value)

    def addInPlace(self, val1, val2):
        for i in xrange(len(val1)):
            val1[i] += val2[i]
        return val1


va = sc.accumulator([0] * 3, VectorAccumulatorParam())

data = range(30)
lines = ssc.queueStream(map(lambda x: sc.parallelize([x]), zip(*[iter(data)] * 3)))

# lines.transform(lambda rdd: rdd.foreach(lambda x: va.add(x)) or rdd) \
#     .foreachRDD(lambda x: print("Now Accumulator Value is ({0})".format(va.value)))
lines.transform(lambda rdd: print("Now Accumulator Value is ({0})".format(va.value)) or rdd) \
    .foreachRDD(lambda rdd: rdd.foreach(lambda x: va.add(x)))

lines.pprint()

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

And output:

```
Now Accumulator Value is ([0, 0, 0])
-------------------------------------------                                     
Time: 2017-07-13 17:23:12
-------------------------------------------
(0, 1, 2)

Now Accumulator Value is ([0, 1, 2])
-------------------------------------------
Time: 2017-07-13 17:23:15
-------------------------------------------
(3, 4, 5)

Now Accumulator Value is ([3, 5, 7])
-------------------------------------------
Time: 2017-07-13 17:23:18
-------------------------------------------
(6, 7, 8)

Now Accumulator Value is ([9, 12, 15])
-------------------------------------------
Time: 2017-07-13 17:23:21
-------------------------------------------
(9, 10, 11)

Now Accumulator Value is ([18, 22, 26])
-------------------------------------------                                     
Time: 2017-07-13 17:23:24
-------------------------------------------
```